# Question about the proof of Cantor's Theorem

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Cantor's Theorem can be stated as follows:

Theorem: Let $A$ be a set. Then $|P(A)|>|A|$, where $P(A)$ is the power-set of $A$.

Proof: Suppose there exists a surjection $\phi: A \rightarrow P(A)$. Let $B=\{a \in A | a \notin \phi(a)\}$. Then since $\phi$ is a surjection, $B=\phi(b)$ for some $b \in A$.

Either $b \in B$ or $b \notin B$. If $b \in B$, we get a contradiction and if $b \notin B$, we also get a contradiction. QED

My question about the proof is how do we know that there exists such a set $B$ as defined in the proof? I ask this question because it is known that a similarly-defined set $C=\{a \in A| a \notin a\}$ is known not to exist: If $C \in C$, we get a contradiction. If $C \notin C$, we also get a contradiction. This is Russell's paradox. Cantor's proof falls apart if we cannot justify the existence of set $B$ in Cantor's proof.

Comment: The set $B$ does exist by the axiom schema of specification.

Comment: And, by the same token, the set $C$ exists as well.

Comment: The set C DOES exist by the Comprehension Axiom Schema. Russell's Paradox comes from assuming$ \{a| a \not \in a\}$  exists. The set B also exists by Comprehension. The idea is that, given a set A, we can obtain a set of all ,and only, those members of A that have some stated property.But we cannot always omit the "A"  from the sentence without allowing paradoxes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The set $B$ exists by the Axiom of Specification. For the same reason, the set $C=\{a\in A|a\notin a\}$ ***does*** exist. The contradiction you speak of only arises if you assume that $C\in A$; this contradiction proves that $C\notin A.$ If we assume the Axiom of Foundation, then $C=A.$ What does ***not*** exist is $\{a|a\notin a\}$; note the difference.